# Are the artworks at the end of each chapter of The Mandalorian concept art or created post-production?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

At the end of each chapter of *The Mandalorian* there's a collection of artworks that's shown. Some of them are near exact depictions of various scenes from that chapter, however, others are never seen.

My question is, **were these artworks created exclusively during concept/development of each chapter, or are they more so created post-production?**

[image: artw]

Honestly they're one of my favorite elements of the series and I always look forward to seeing them.

Comment: The following article seems to suggest that it is additional art for the show, but I want to try to find a better source before I attempt to make an answer. (They're SO COOL though!!! :D ) https://comicbook.com/starwars/2019/11/22/star-wars-details-the-mandalorian-end-credits-concept-art-revealed/

Answer (score 3):

Based on everything I've read and the artist names credited, the message I get from Disney and Star Wars feeds is that these are indeed pre-production concept artworks.

https://d23.com/the-mandalorian-concept-art/

Given the documentaries on how they are shooting The Mandalorian, with digital imagery physically displayed behind live actors, it feels pretty plausible that they could go from the aforementioned concept art, to digital backgrounds, to finished product, and come out looking remarkably close to the concept art.

https://www.slashfilm.com/the-mandalorian-stagecraft-photos/